# Setting a property from an interface with a stub

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

I'm creating a stubed interface and passing it into my test method like shown below. I'm stubbing the interface (StubISeries) that gets passed into the test method. If `comparisonSeries.Key` is only a get in the interface, can I set the value in the stub without adding a set property to the interface?

```
var series = new SomeNameSpace.Fakes.StubISeries();
series.Key = something to set the key here?
DateTime date = formReport.ResolveDate(series, DateTime.Now);

public override DateTime ResolveDate(ISeries comparisonSeries, DateTime targetDate)
{
    switch (comparisonSeries.Key)
    {
        case SeriesKey.SomeKey1:
        case SeriesKey.SomeKey2:
        case SeriesKey.SomeKey3:
        case SeriesKey.SomeKey4:
        case SeriesKey.SomeKey5:
            return DateHelper.PreviousOrCurrentQuarterEnd(targetDate);
        default:
            break;
    }

    return base.ResolveDate(comparisonSeries, targetDate);
}
```

Comment: if you are using "MS Fakes"  you can set the delegate that will be used by  property get of the stub objects eg:  series.KeyGet=()=>keyvalueYouNeed;  there should be a KeyGet property on your StubISeries?

Comment: I tried (series.KeyGet = () => SeriesKey.MyKey) but the compiler says: "you cannot convert source type 'lambda' expression' to target type 'Microsoft.qyualitytools.testing.fakes.fakesdelegates+func'1'

Comment: It's funny. There was a red line under the above expression but when I compiled and then ran the test it went away.

Answer (score 0):

Given the following definitions of the `ISeries` interface and `SeriesKey` enum

```
public enum SeriesKey
{
    SomeKey1,
    SomeKey2,
    SomeKey3
}

public interface ISeries
{
    SeriesKey Key { get; }
}
```

You can write the following test with a StubISeries generated by Fakes.

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTestMethod()
{
    var stub = new StubISeries();
    stub.KeyGet = () => SeriesKey.SomeKey1;
    Assert.AreEqual(SeriesKey.SomeKey1, ((ISeries)stub).Key);
}
```